# How to find list of all logged in users in CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using the standard Auth component in CakePHP/MySQL and would like to view all the logged in users as an admin.  In addition I would also like to "kick out" users from their session, so their next click on the page forces them to the login screen.

In my core config I am using the cake/tmp for sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to use the database for sessions: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#database-sessions

That way you can retrieve a list of sessions, and delete them from your administration panel as you deem fit to do so.

Comment: Ok, but are the sessions linked to the user information somehow? Would I just get a list of "sess_49s5rolkc8e8dgcu6rr67j70s4rs1slj"? How would I link back to the user id/name?

Comment: Your application code wouldn’t change; sessions would just be saved to the database instead of the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin will help you: https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Whos-Online-Plugin

Comment: Ok.. but sometimes users from a big organisation will have the same IP address?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is provided by Google analytics:

Implementation is provided in the below links:

http://www.elisa-dbi.co.uk/blog/how-to-segment-logged-in-users-using-google-analytics/

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/37698/tracking-logged-in-vs-non-logged-in-users-in-google-analytics