# How to limit users to one session with CakePHP 3?

Tags: session, cakephp

I have auth working fine. Users can log in and out, no problem. The thing is, if users share a login, they can all be logged in at the same time as the one user. Not good.

I need to have CakePHP know when a user is logged in, which I assume is a process started using:

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'database'
]
```

As per the [Sessions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#database-sessions) book page.

It's then I get lost. Unless I have missed it there is no reference to limiting users to one active session each. Has anyone come across this before and, if so, how did you work around it?

To clarity:

All sessions deleted from DB & all cookies deleted in browser = nothing set in either when visiting the /users/login page (incidentally, this has been set up as per the tutorials - nothing fancy).

Login = session set in db with id corresponding to cookie in browser. Exactly what you'd expect.

Logout (which then redirects back to login) = old session removed then replaced by another in DB and cookie. Different id. So something is picking up the expired cookie and refreshing it. Hmm.

The information held in the cookie is just the session id. In the DB it's simply:

Session id | a blob | expiry time

Comment: Since you're using database sessions, you can query the sessions table for the user when that user logs in and delete all sessions for that user before logging them in. This is more of a workaround though.
Somewhat relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022677/how-to-find-list-of-all-logged-in-users-in-cakephp-2-x

Comment: Thanks for that. I have progressed to the point where the session is deleted on logout but another is instantly recreated when the user is redirected to the users/login page (without them logging in! It's driving me crazy!). I cannot find what is setting this cookie/session. To explain the steps: user with no cookie visits /users/login (no cookie/session set), logs in (all fine - session shows in db), logs out (session killed in db) and is redirected to /users/login. Then, sat at the login prompt with no user interaction required, the user has an active session in the db. Odd.

Comment: When you delete the session directly from the database, it doesn't delete the cookie from their system, but the cookie on their system should be useless since it doesn't have any associated data on your database. The people you log out by deleting the session shouldn't be able to do anything that requires a login. Are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: The strange bit is that a new cookie is set prior to login. The id string in this cookie is matched by one created in the db. Yet at the same time they have to require login credentials to do anything. I'm trying to work out what part of auth is hunting for an expired cookie and generating a new one. Is this making any sense to you?

Comment: Would the line 'if ($this->request->is('post'))' have anything to do with a new session being set? The cake 3 book says 'The above code will attempt to first identify a user by using the POST data. If successful we set the user info to the session so that it persists across requests and then redirect to either the last page they were visiting or a URL specified in the loginRedirect config. If the login is unsuccessful, a flash message is set.' I think that has to be it but I'm tired and need sleep.

Comment: Nah, that line just checks if the request is post. Can you check what data is saved in the database for the session that's created prior to log in? It might give you more insight into what is going on.

Comment: Does the new session in the DB have the user information of the person who you logged out? Or does it just have a session with empty fields? By the way, you might want to edit the question with the additional info you provided in the comments.

Comment: Have edited as suggested and added the info you mentioned. I have made no progress with this frustratingly.

Comment: You didn't actually answered the question by @dragmosh , ie after logging out, does the "new" session in the database actually contain any user information (which I'd doubt unless something goes horribly wrong)? The session being refreshed is totally fine and the expected behavior, you cannot have sessions and not have sessions at the same time, either your app uses sessions, or it doesn't, what's important is that the user information is being wiped out.

Comment: Correct, I didn't answer it. The session is refreshed and that's all - user info is wiped out.

Comment: Before starting session for a user check existing session for that user if count exceeds allowed deny access else ready to go;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you save `users` and `sessions` in a database (by default in cakePHP it is named `sessions`).

Add an `active_session` field, update it upon login, check it on requests to ensure that current user session id matches the last one stored in the database.

On Login action do:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `active_session`='$session_id';
```

When user goes to a page that requires login, you search that value:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `active_session` = '$session_id';
```

If the user signs in other place, the previous session key gets overwriten, and the SELECT above returns an *empty* result-set.

It's possible to clean the old session token before the update, so this way old session will be destroyed on per user basis.

---

Be careful, if you are using `AuthComponent`, it might rotate sessions itself, for more information you may find in [the corresponding section of CakePHP manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#rotating-session-identifiers).

I'd definitely go [`AuthComponent`-way](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html), and wouldn't re-invent the wheel in CakePHP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that - will test and report back. From testing thus far it seems that the AuthComponent does only change the session id on logout/timeout.

Comment: @pmelon - looking forward to hearing the results of your test. I'm going to be facing this exact situation shortly on a project.

Comment: @Farside - Thank you for the response, I beginning to wonder if this question would get any love! Thanks for making a detailed response as well.

Comment: This answer helps a lot, but it does not explain how to do it using the CakePHP preferred method (AuthComponent). It would be great if the answer could be improved in that way, or a new answer could be provided with an example code.

Answer (score 0):

I tie users to their cell phone. Every day they get a new 6 digit code via twilio sms. Makes it hard to share logins, but not impossible. Ultimately, I would like to track how many different machines a users uses per day and establish some fair use limitations. If a user uses three or four machines in a day, that's fine, but when they start using the same user id on twenty or fifty machines a day, that might be a problem.